# How can i get placeholder text from prompt via selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, prompt

I need to get the default value from prompt via selenium.
If this is my prompt :

```
prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
```

I want to get "Harry Potter" to my String

I tried use this :

```
alert.Text;
```

But i get the first text "`Please enter your name:`"

The prompt :

```
var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
```

my code :

```
String name = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

Comment: It seems like you would want to get the value attribute, at least if no one has changed it yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
 // switch to alert
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 // accept the prompt without changing anything
 alert.accept();
 // now get the default value
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 String defaultVal = (String) js.executeScript("return person");
 //print the default value from prompt
 System.out.println(defaultVal);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it does not work i get error message "javascript error: person is not defined"

Comment: `var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");` is this the line that you see in the prompt line? I mean does the prompt return the value into person?